# Is overfitting always a bad thing?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, xgboost, kaggle

I am currently participating in several machine learning competitions as I am trying to learn this field.

For a regression problem, I'm using a `xgboost`. 
Here is the procedure I use :

After feature engineering, I split my data into 2 sets, one training set, and one testing set, as usual. Then I fit my `xgboost` on the training set and validate on the testing set. Here are the results I get : (I also show the public set results when I used the trained algorithm to predict the target for submission, the metric is mae).

```
Iteration  training score  testing score  public score   
100        8.05            12.14          17.50
150        7.10            11.96          17.30
```

Remarks :

- All data sets (train/test/public set) are roughly the same size, approximately 200 000 samples.
- It is a time serie, so I didn't shuffle the data when splitting, even though shuffling it doesn't change the results..
- I also tried to train my xgboost on the samples that are temporaly close to the public data set, but the results aren't better.
- When I train on all data (train+test) before I submit, I got an improvement on public score of 0.35.

Here are my questions :

- Can we really estimate the over-fitting by just looking at the difference between training and testing score? Or is it only an indicator of over-fitting?
- Why does my submission score improved by increasing the number of iterations even if it shows that I'm increasingly over-fitting?
- Why is the improvement in submission score even better than the improvement in the testing score?
- Why testing score and submission score are not closer? Why do I have systemically a big difference between testing and submission score, regardless of the hyperparameters or "over-fitting rate".

Is this statement true: If the ratio of useful information learned over the useless information (training set specific information) is greater than 1, then you can continue over-fitting and still improve the model?

I hope it's not too confusing, I'm sorry I may not have the proper vocabulary.
I have to mention that, even with over-fitting and the big difference between testing and public score, I still am currently the second on the leaderboard with 50 people participating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all understand what over-fitting is.

you can see over fit when the training score is increasing (or error is decreasing) while your testing set score is decreasing (or error is increasing)

Over fit is when your training model is too precise and doesn't generalize on the problem you try to solve. In other words its too FIT for the training, and the training alone, so that it cannot solve/predict a different data set.

In your example it seems like both the errors of the train and the test are decreasing, which means you are not over fitting.

Over fitting is always a **bad** thing.

As for your current problem. If you want to run multiple cross validations, or manually split your data for many training and many testing sets you can do the following:

1. Split the data for training and testing (50%, 50%) or (70%, 30%), what ever you think is right for you
2. Then, randomly sample with X% your training data, and it'll be the training set.
3. Randomly sample the testing data with Y% and it'll be your testing set
4. I suggest X = Y = 75%. And the above split to be 70% training and 30% testing.

As for your questions:

1. It is just an indicator for over fit.
2. You are not over fitting by your example
3. Score will varies on different data sets
4. Same answer as 3

Adding a picture to describe over fitting: [image]

There is a point (10) in complexity where keep training will decrease the training error but will INCREASE the testing error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I'm not overfitting, what justify the difference between train and test scores?

Comment: Lets consider the following exemple : 
(iteration, train score, test score):


(50, 15.00, 15.00),


(100, 14.00, 14.30)


In this case, going from 50 to 100 iterations, the train score increased by 1, but the test score increased only by 0.30, I previously thought that the 0.70 missing were actually overfit. Since the algorithm improoved his score on train by learning "new stuff" and when applied to test set, it didn't increased so much, for me that is just telling that the 0.70 missing is not general to the problem, thus it is overfiting. What is wrong with that reasoning?

Comment: Is it really impossible to simultaneously learning general relationship of the data and also learning specific relationships related to training set?
I mean, from one iteration to another, the algorithm is learning several things. So why would it be impossible for the algorithm to learn useful information as well as useless information?

Comment: @Luc What justify the differences between your training and testing is that they are both different data sets from different time. As I've mentioned in my post, OVERFITTING is when your training set keeps improving and your testing set getting worse. In xgboost in particular you can train untill perfection. (meaning that your training set can get 100% accuracy). But that doesn't mean its good because it will NOT GENERALIZE on different data sets/scenarios/events and so on.

Comment: Yes I understand, but are you sure that it is impossible to overfit (a little) while also learning useful things? At the end, if the algorithm learn more useful thing than useless things it still can increase test score while still overfitting a little bit? With your saying this is impossible, but why? Can you explain me this. Why it is impossible to both overfitting and rightfitting?

Comment: If you learn more useful things then useless things then YOU ARE NOT OVER FITTING :> :> :> As I said, the overall training error is reduced as well as your testing error

Comment: Ok, I understand your frustration, but 'im trying to understand :p I'm sorry :p and thank you for your time and answers. 
So the situation I described is possible but it isn't called overfitting, I get it now. So how such a behavior is called? Should I be careful about this? Or should I just stick to be careful at an increasing testing error and do not care as soon as my testing error is decreasing?

Comment: There is a feature in xgboost called "early_stopping". This feature was designed to avoid overfitting. In this feature you decide how many boosts u'd like to make (without improving the testing score) until you stop training your model. This feature will also return you the best iteration of your model (So you will know exactly when to stop). Avoiding Overfitting IS VERY IMPORTANT. Don't neglect it as it can drastically fool you in other situations. As long as you keep track of your training error and testing error and see they both decrease you are in the safe zone.

Comment: I'm already using early_stopping_rounds :p, it just that I thought if  test_score < train_score then is it overfitting. Now I understand that this behaviour isn't included in the overfitting definition. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: BTW, you are talking about test_error and train_error right? these are 2 different concepts. here you try to minimize error. :>

Comment: Saying "test_score < train_score" or "test_error > train_error "is not the same?? When I use score and errors I mean, a lower error correspond to a better score.

Comment: Yes but it can be confusing. There are evaluation metrics that generate score you want to maximize like AUC ROCc, Precision Recall, MAP and so on.. And evaluation metrics that generate error (you'd like to minimize) like RMSE, MAE and so on..

Comment: Ok I see, I was confused on overfitting but not on this subject :p
Anyway, thank you again for making me understand better overfitting.

Answer (score 3):

Just some thoughts that might help you...

The final result of a Kaggle competition is the private leaderboard, where your model will be tested on data you haven't yet seen. It is no use optimising your model to predict well on the public leaderboard (submission dataset) and then dropping 10 places because you overfitted and didn't cross-validate, so your model didn't generalise well. You have to do some cross-validation and I would advise you to trust the results.

Note that in percentage terms, your decreases in MAE are 11.8%, 1.5% and 1.1%, so your submission score is improving the least.

You have to be careful sometimes with time series data – which part of the data is most similar to the public/private leaderboard data? For example, if you have a years’ worth of data and you train on Jan-Jun 16, test on Jul-Dec 16 and then validate (submit) on Jan-Jun 17 then you might expect a better result for your submission than you test dataset. In that case, you might discard Jul-Dec 16 data completely and train/test only on Jan-Jun 16.

You are obviously doing something right if you are in 2nd place but please remember to cross-validate. There were competitions in the past where people fall hundreds of places because their models didn't generalise well!

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I'll be careful :). I have been struggling with machine learning, as far as I have experienced it, I feel like in machine learning nothing is really true nor wrong. When looking for something, I always find every possible answer on internet. For instance, does xgboost need one hot encoding? Usually yes, but sometimes no. I feel it is always the same with everything. I feel its like a physics experiment, you cannot tell if it will work until you tried it.

Comment: You're welcome. Often the best answer is: "read what other people say, then try various options and find out yourself". As for xgboost requiring one-hot encoding, I would say that it does because otherwise it will treat the categoricals as ordered, which might not be the case. On the other hand, expanding a categorical to 50 boolean flags may not be the most sensible idea.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this image trying to fit data points: 
[image]

your function will fit given data points perfectly, resulting in Xi squared lower than 1.

Further see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_chi-squared_statistic

In essence:

- your model will not generalize
- work well on the test set

P.S check kaggle leader boards pre and post win. They evaluate on a different subset of data. Mostly leading algorithms do badly on the 'not seen before' data.

Comment: I agree, thank you for the example, but what I don't understand is the difference between train and test score, regardless of public LB score.
What justify the difference between the two scores? If i'm not overfitting, where are those difference coming from? The only answer I can find is that the training set does not contain the necessary information (i.e. to small) for the algorithm to understand?
Also, Is it possible to simultaneously overfitting and also learning useful information?